# Match Question Mark in rewrite rule using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried it in a different way that is also not working for me.

**Match Question Mark in rewrite rule**

please help me on this

Redirect to different url

```
http://localhost/crb/index.html?q=xxxxxxxx
```

To

```
http://localhost/crb/demo/result?q=xxxxxxxx
```

I tried this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^crb/index.html?q=xxxxxxxx(.*)$ http://localhost/crb/demo/result?q=xxxxxxxx$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: A simple [**Google Search**](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=redirect%20with%20.htaccess) would've shown you how to do this. Atleast attempt to solve the question before asking for answers.

Comment: I have tried  below redirect rule is not working 
Redirect 301 /crb/index.html?q=xxxxxxxx http://localhost/crb/demo/result?q=xxxxxxxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rewrite based on query string use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=xxxxxxxx(.*)$
RewriteRule  ^/?crb/index.html  http://localhost/crb/demo/result?q=xxxxxxxx%1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.This rewrite rule is not working for me .I have pasted below the .htaccess file.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Is redirecting to wrong URL? or not redirecting at all?

Comment: Not redirecting at all

Comment: Where did you put your `.htaccess`? document root? what address do you enter in address bar?

Comment: I have placed .htacess file under the documentroot .

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^q=xxxxxxxx(.*)$
RewriteRule  crb/index.html  http://demo.xxxx.com/crb/demo/result?q=xxxxxxxx%1 [R=301,NC]

Comment: I edited my answer, check it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Query String Append (QSA) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^crb/index.html$ crb/demo/result [NC,L,QSA]
```

This should append the existing query string (q=xxxxxxxx) to the new url.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

If this code doesn't work, modify it a little and try again.